# sharing a custom playlist on facebook

Tags: facebook, share

[image]

In the above share snapshot, playlist being shared in a customised way.

I used all the og:tags type|music, music.album, og:audio artist. But mine share happens like this only.

[image]

Is the customised feature available only for whitelist partners? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Facebook Open Graph Music is available to white-listed partners only. And so is posting custom HTML5 content into timeline; so the most you could do is use your own flash player to display your playlist.

Comment: http://patari.pk/home/album/Braadri-Broadcast-Singles is the share from this link is in flash , it seems html5 only

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpatari.pk%2Fhome%2Falbum%2FBraadri-Broadcast-Singles

Comment: Using debugger tool shows og tags for all music songs in playlist. Can I conclude this link shares thru html5 and then this site is a whitelist partner ?

Comment: This isn’t custom HTML5 content, but a player rendered by Facebook itself, based on the OG meta data. And yes, they must be a white-listed partner, otherwise this won’t work.

Comment: Oh thanks. Very hard to believe.. A very unknown site has become the whitelist partner. Can anyone apply to be a whitelist partner?

Comment: There is no official application process AFAIK; it's more of a you gotta know the right people thing. If you spend enough on advertising, you get assigned someone to directly talk to at FB, and they'll be able to put you in touch with the right people.